# Css Form element alignment

Tags: css

I have a html form(ASP.Net MVC). The input textboxes are wrapped in a div with a class name of editor-field. Example html:

```
<div class="editor-field">
<input id="EmployeeNo" type="text" value="" name="EmployeeNo">
</div>
```

The style for the editor-field class is:

```
.display-field, .editor-field 
{
   float: left;
}
```

The textboxes are all way of to the right, how can I get it to be closer to the labels? I've tried adding margins and padding, but it doesnt work.

Comment: Maybe you need to add the complete code. This is not helping. By the way...maybe a simple table can help you out.

Comment: Post a demo on jsfiddle plz. And be careful with `float`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ create an example for your problem

Comment: Just solved my own problem. The width of the .editor-label was too big. Works fine now.

Thanks!

Comment: is any specific browser it's floating to right?, i have checked in chrome it's left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the .editor-label. It had a width that was too big.